# How to Export ASP.NET grid to pdf

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to export asp.net grid to PDF with following type as

> CSS

styling, text and images with or without

> itextsharp

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After binding data to gridview

```
  protected void btnExportPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
   "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
   Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
   GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
   GridView1.DataBind();
   GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
   StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
   Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f,10f,10f,0f);
   HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
   PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
   pdfDoc.Open();
   htmlparser.Parse(sr);
   pdfDoc.Close();
   Response.Write(pdfDoc);
   Response.End(); 
 }
```